# Add subview when UITableView row is selected?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, subview

I'm working on an iPhone app that parses an XML file into a UITableView. It lists all of the titles of items within the XML file, and I'm trying to have the cell expand and add the body content of the selected item when a specified cell is selected.

I can get the cell to expand correctly, but when I have had no luck adding the body content as a subview. When populating the cell at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I can add the body content and it displays fine.

My question is, how do I add a subview to the selected cell after it has been selected?

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, with the 'functioning' bodyLabel commented out:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
issue *curIssue = [[parser issues] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];


    CGRect nameFrame = CGRectMake(0,2,300,15);
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameFrame];
    nameLabel.tag = 1;
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];

    CGRect bodyFrame = CGRectMake(0,16,300,60);

    UILabel *bodyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:bodyFrame];
    bodyLabel.tag = 2;
    bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 10;
    bodyLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    bodyLabel.hidden = YES;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:bodyLabel];

}



    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    nameLabel.text     = [curIssue name];

    UILabel *bodyLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    bodyLabel.text     = [curIssue body];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function, where I'm trying to add the subview. When trying to execute, I receive a EXC_BAD_ACESS exception when trying to alloc the `*bodyLabel` element.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSInteger defCellHeight  = 15;
NSInteger heightModifier = 10;
if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]){
    return defCellHeight * heightModifier;
}

return defCellHeight;
}
```

My `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function, which allows the cell to grow/shrink:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
    BOOL isSeld = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

    NSNumber *seldIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSeld];
    [selectedIndexes setObject:seldIndex forKey:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[tableView viewWithTag:2];
    label.hidden = NO;

    [curIssView beginUpdates];
    [curIssView endUpdates];
}
```

And finally, the `cellIsSelected` helper function which returns true if the cell is selected:

```
-(bool) cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSNumber *selIndex = [selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
    return selIndex == nil ? FALSE : [selIndex boolValue];
}
```

You can find the full source file [here](http://cwardcode.com/SecondVIewController.m).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're allocating and adding the same UILabel's multiple times. You should only have to do it once within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You might also want to set the `bodyLabel` to hidden in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, then set it to not hidden when the cell has been selected. With something like:

```
bodyLabel.hidden = YES;
```

Another thing. Why are you deselecting the row within the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Ah, darn. This is my first foray into objective-c, so I'm not 100% on what I'm even doing. Most of it has been trial and error. The UILabel's hidden field is great! I've moved the creation of the label/body fields back into `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. However, I'm not too clear on where, or how I could set the label back to unhidden. I think it would be something like this, within the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[tableView viewWithTag:2];
    label.hidden = NO;
However, this only displays the last cell's body, regardless of which is selected.

Comment: Set `bodyLabel.hidden = NO;` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. To get the index path of the row being selected use `BOOL isSeld = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath.row];` seems like you were just missing the `.row`. Also add in to `if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a UILabel in heightForRowAtIndexPath?
If you're trying to add it to the row, use the cellForRowAtIndexPath method you used above.

Simply adding a subview to the UITableViewCell or anywhere else in view with UIView's addSubview method inside of didSelectRowAtIndexPath will work for displaying a subview when a UITableView row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

To add a subview to the cell when you select it, it's pretty straightforward:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
    /*
     .. your other setup
    */

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:<your subview>];
}
```